# How to use git pull without entering the passphrase

Tags: ssh, git, public-key, github

I'm trying to pull from a GitHub repository in an unattended way, but everytime I do it I get:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/yc2/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

And I have to enter it for it work. I managed to skip it by using

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add <I enter my passphrase>
```

But that's only maintained on the actual session, but I need to do it with a PHP script, but if it asks the password, the script doesn't works, so how can I make it to not ask the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ssh-keygen -p` to change the pass phrase on the key, including setting no pass phrase

```
ssh-keygen -p
Enter file in which the key is (/home/iain/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/iain/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa
Enter old passphrase: <existing pass phrase>
Key has comment '/home/iain/.ssh/tmp/id_rsa'
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

If you use this key for other things you may be safer generating a keypair just for your program to use.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use it from a script perhaps you can remove the passphrase.